# Настройка удалённого доступа к Asus Wl 520GC

Tags: роутер, маршрутизатор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Web интерфейс у него такой, но все на английском и не могу разобраться как настроить удалённый доступ к нему. Чтобы например через 4G мог бы подключиться к нему.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь есть Multiple Language Manual, в том числе на русском
https://www.asus.com/ru/Networking/WL520gC/HelpDesk_Manual/